# How to apply a funded equity collar to illiquid stocks?

Tags: equities, derivatives, financial-engineering, margin, collateral

I investigate a specific case of the funded **equity collar** [[1](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/39323/funded-equity-collars-and-margin-loans?newreg=ed5f5fb5a94e48a8a8907b8db4d3cd32.)].

Let's assume that counterparty $A$ already has a stake in share $XYZ$ and wants to get funding out of it from a bank $B$, which does not want to get too much credit exposure from the resulting operation.

If I refer to this question [[1](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/39323/funded-equity-collars-and-margin-loans?newreg=ed5f5fb5a94e48a8a8907b8db4d3cd32.)], bank $B$ can offer a **margin loan** to counterparty $A$ which must pledge its shares $XYZ$ and buy a put option strike $k$ and sell a call strike $(k+\epsilon)$ on shares $XYZ$ (see existing question above). In that case, bank $B$ will have to delta hedge the collar by short-selling shares, which had to be borrowed earlier from a third counterparty.

However, what if the borrowing and lending market is not liquid enough, such that bank $B$ might not be able to borrow shares $XYZ$ from the market. It would then mean that delta hedging is just not possible or should be done via the shares in the pledge, which is legally forbidden a priori.

Is there an alternative to the margin loan (pledge + financing) in that particular situation of illiquid lending market? For instance, would it feasible to transform the pledge into a stock lending (GMSLA) or a repo (GMRA) without modifying the rest of the structure ?

Comment: Interesting, maybe @Daneel Olivaw can provide help since he asked the original question.